# Chance PI Tag of Multi-Stage Symbol in Processboook with VBA

Tags: vba, osisoft

How I can change PI Tag of Multi-Stage Symbol in ProcessBook with VBA. I can get actual PI Tag with
`a = Whitepilotlight2_1.GetTagName(1)` for example but a don't find a command to change it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: As a side-note, PI ProcessBook has been officially retired, and most companies are phasing it out over the next year, so probably best to avoid doing new work in the tool - I'd suggest speaking to your support team about options for migrating your displays through to PI AF & PI Vision. Most displays can be migrated automatically to PI Vision, but if there is embedded VBA code in them then it will take more manual effort.

Answer (score 0):

I found it. It should be something like the following:

```
f = symbolname.GetMultiState.SetPtTagName("PiTagName")
```